# Surface area of a plane wing

Tags: calculus, integration, area, surfaces

I want to determine the surface area of an aircraft wing using calculus, specifically focusing on the cross-sectional area (thickness distribution) formula. Although I am unsure if there exists a specific formula for this purpose, I am interested in understanding how to calculate the curved surface area of an airplane wing without relying on aerodynamic equations. I have provided images for those less familiar with aerodynamics and the aviation industry, which may aid in visualizing the three-dimensional aspects. In the figures, the cross-sectional area is defined using airfoil equations, incorporating a thickness distribution equation. [image: 3D plane wing]Second image

[image]It is noteworthy that the cross-sectional area of aircraft wings tends to increase as they approach the fuselage, with C1 and C2 representing the initial and final chord lengths. The variable L denotes the length of the aircraft wing.

General Thickness Distribution formula:
$$y_{t}=\pm5ct[0.2969\sqrt{α}-0.1260α-0.3516α^{2}+0.2843α^{3}-0.1015α^{4}]$$

Thickness Distribution formula for NACA 2412 (which I want to find): $$y_{t}=\pm0.60[0.2969\sqrt{α}-0.1260α-0.3516α^{2}+0.2843α^{3}-0.1015α^{4}]$$

Where c is the chord length, α = x/c and t is the maximum thickness expressed as a fraction of the chord length. In other words, 1/100 last two digits×chord length.

It is not necessary to use the given values, but you can if you want.

$$L = 30m$$
$$C1= 3m$$
$$C2= 1.5m$$

Comment: The thickness distribution formula provided by you is NOT CORRECT.

Comment: I can only make sense of $f(x)$ if the solid wing cross section is symmetric above and below the horizontal central line. Then the function represents the height above (below) that line. But then it must vary with C and it doesn't.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I fixed it

Comment: What about the camber line?

Comment: I think I misunderstood some things. Without the camber line, this is a symmetrical airfoil, but what good is it if I use the camber line? I put the equations into desmos but I didn't get a curved airfoil. (camber line equation is Front (0≤x<p)                                 Back (p≤x≤1)
 $$y_{c}=\frac{M}{p^{2}}(2px-x^{2})\ \ \ \ \ y_{c}=\frac{M}{(1-p)^{2}}(1-2p+2px-x^{2})$$    Where M presents first digit (maximum camber) divided by 100 and p presents second digit (position of the maximum camber) divided by 10.

Comment: So $$\frac{0.02}{0.4^{2}}\left(0.8α-α^{2}\right)\ \left\{0\le α<0.4\right\}$$ and $$\frac{0.02}{\left(1-0.4\right)^{2}}\left(1-0.8+0.8α-α^{2}\right)\ \left\{0.4<α\le1\right\}$$ for Naca 2412

Comment: Can you please clarify: Is this 1. a mathematical question or 2. a practical one, and A. do you want an exact answer or B. a numerical approximation? <> (Offhand, 1A looks impossible in terms of "elementary functions", while for 2B you may get an estimate to within a few percent from the area of the trapezoid projection of the wing into a horizontal plane.)

Comment: It is a mathematical question and I know that finding exact answer is nearly impossible so a numerical approximation by using calculus is enough for me.

Comment: The formula for the camber gives you a curve from $x=0$ to $x=1$. It is not the airfoil; it is inside the airfoil. You then have to project points perpendicular to the curve above and below it to get points on the surface of the airfoil. The Wikipedia page has quite explicit steps (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil#Equation_for_a_cambered_4-digit_NACA_airfoil). Note that you will be plotting the surface points *parametrically*. You will not end up with a function $y=f(x)$ for either the top or bottom surface.

Comment: In the thickness distribution for NACA 2412, $t = 0.12$, so $5ct = 0.60 c$, not $0.60$. Leaving out the factor $c$ means you have an incorrect formula.

Comment: I'm still puzzled why anyone wants to measure the surface area of an airfoil. It's not a particularly useful property to know about an airfoil and I can't help but wonder if you really wanted something else instead. See [How do I calculate the area of a curved irregular plane such as an aeroplane wing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2613449/139123)

Answer (score 0):

Considering $f\left(x,c\right)$ where $c = c_2+\frac{(c_1-c_2)l}{L}$ as the upper wing profile parametrized by the position along the wing span, the length element is given by

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2+1}=\sigma(x,c)
$$

then the upper wing area is given by

$$
\int_{l=0}^{l=L}dl\int_{x=0}^{x=c_2+\frac{(c_1-c_2)l}{L}}dx \sigma(x,l)
$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which calculates a good area approximation. Here we consider the upper wing profile.

```
f[x_, c_] := 0.6 (0.2969 Sqrt[x/c] - 0.1260 x/c - 0.3516 (x/c)^2 + 0.2843 (x/c)^3 - 0.1015 (x/c)^4)

sigma[x_, c_] := Sqrt[1 + 0.36` (-(0.126`/c) - (0.7032` x)/c^2 + (0.8529` x^2)/c^3 - (0.406` x^3)/c^4 + 0.14845`/(c Sqrt[x/c]))^2]

c2 = 1.5;
c1 = 3;
L  = 30;
Quiet@NIntegrate[NIntegrate[sigma[x, c2 + ((c1 - c2) l)/L], {x, 0, c2 + ((c1 - c2) l)/L}], {l, 0, L}]

(* 67.8476 *)
```

NOTE

A coarse area approximation is obtained by doing

```
(c1 + c1)/2 L // N  

(* 67.5 *)
```

Comment: From the figure, it looks like you tapered the chord of the wing but did not taper the thickness. Both must be tapered in order to have a NASA 2412 airfoil.

Comment: As I said in the answer, the area calculation is for the upper wing profile. The total area is twice this number. It agrees with the coarse approximation.

Comment: The coarse approximation has the same flaw. The wing you measured has an area not too different from the requested wing, but it's still not the same wing. Also, the wing is not symmetrical, so we should not expect the bottom area to be the same. It is usually less.

Comment: It just hardly seems worth putting all this work into plotting the correct section at the wing root if you're going to make all these simplifications to the problem afterward. You could just measure the planform area and double it to get two surfaces, and you'd be within a few percent.

Comment: I placed the profiles all with origin at  $x = 0$. It seems to me that the origin point of each profile along the wing is missing. This is the only problem I can think of and it is due to lack of information. If this is not the problem, then I withdraw from the issue due to incompetence on my part.

Comment: I think part of this is my difficulty parsing the script. Looking again, I think your coarse approximation **is** the planform area, and indeed it is not surprising to see it is close to the curved surface you computed. (And it will also be close to any good measurement of the upper surface.) I'm still not sure if the maximum chord or the minimum chord (or neither) gives the upper surface of a NACA 2412 airfoil in this script.

Comment: I see now that the thickness error I was complaining about is actually in the original question, not something you introduced.